# Angular ajax failed using $http

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

I got an error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'success' of undefined` when using $http and my custom service.

My app.js :

```
app.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'topicContent', function($scope, $http, topicContent){

  topicContent.request().success(function(data){
    $scope.threadContent = data;
    console.log(data);
  });

}]);

app.factory('topicContent', ['$http', function($http){

    var query = function() {
        return
          $http({
            url: "http://www.corsproxy.com/daysof.me/lowyat/thread.php",
            method: "GET"
        });
    }

    return {
        request : function(){
            return query();
        }


    }
}]);
```

This is so strange, I couldn't find any flaw of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that this code

```
var query = function() {
    return
      $http({
        url: "http://www.corsproxy.com/daysof.me/lowyat/thread.php",
        method: "GET"
    });
}
```

is equivalent to this one:

```
var query = function() {
    return;
      $http({
        url: "http://www.corsproxy.com/daysof.me/lowyat/thread.php",
        method: "GET"
    });
}
```

due to automatic semicolon insertion in javascript. Note that there is semicolon `;` after `return`. So the solution is to move `$http` to the same line after `return` statement:

```
return $http({ ... });
```

Read about in what situations javascript interpreter inserts semicolon `;` automatically, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi). In your case after `return` interpreter will insert `;` which makes `query` function return `undefined`. Hence the error you are getting.